# gihtub API get issues using repository ID as parameter

Tags: github-api

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

It is possible to get all/open/closed issues from the GitHub repo using this API endpoint

`https://api.github.com/{org}/{repo}/issues`..

couldn't find anything in the docs, but I wanted to make sure if there is a way to pull the same information using repository id?
since repo id is unique for any GitHub repo
something like

`https://api.github.com/{repository_id}/issues`

Answer (score 2):

You can use
`https://api.github.com/repositories/{repository_id}/issues`

Add `?state=<closed/open>` to filter the results.
For example: `https://api.github.com/repositories/23096959/issues?state=closed`

This API is undocumented, but [according to GitHub support](https://github.com/piotrmurach/github/issues/283#issuecomment-249092851) it can be relied on.

Relevant github pr: https://github.com/piotrmurach/github/pull/284